# Issues with implementing async.parallel in node.io

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, node.io

The code as listed here will give partial output and then an error (self.htmlparser.parseChunk).  When using async.series instead of async.parallel, this example works as expected

the ping webservice will wait 2 seconds and then output "pong", in order to mock a webservice call

**app.coffee**

```
async = require 'async'
start = (new Date()).getTime()

require('node.io').scrape () ->
    @ping = (callback, n) =>
            @getHtml 'http://localhost:8888/ping', (err, $, data) => 
                diff = (new Date()).getTime() - start
                console.log "#{n} : #{diff}"
                callback err, data
    async.parallel [
        (callback) =>
            @ping callback, 1
        ,
        (callback) =>
            @ping callback, 2
        ,
        (callback) =>
            @ping callback, 3
        ,
        ], (err,results) =>
            @exit err if err?
            console.log n for n in results
            @emit 'done'
```

**Output with async.series**

```
1 : 2079
2 : 4089
3 : 6093
1
2
3
done
OK: Job complete
```

**Output with async.parallel**

```
3 : 2079
/home/nodeuser/src/nodews/client/node_modules/node.io/lib/node.io/request.js:296
                    self.htmlparser.parseChunk(chunk);
TypeError: Cannot call method 'parseChunk' of null
```

**Sys Info**

```
nodeuser@ubuntu:~/src/nodews/client$ node -v && coffee -v && npm -v
v0.4.12
CoffeeScript version 1.1.3
1.0.106

nodeuser@ubuntu:~/src/nodews/client$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 2.6.38-12-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 28 14:27:32 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64    x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Does `async.parallel` work as expected if you only pass in a single task?

Comment: yes it does, 2 or more gives an error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [node.io](https://github.com/chriso/node.io/) source, it seems that `scrape` creates a single `Job` instance, which creates a single [htmlparser](https://github.com/tautologistics/node-htmlparser) instance when needed and destroys it when parsing is done (i.e. when all data from a request has been fed in). So you can't parse multiple sources in parallel from a single `scrape`. Instead, use node.io's lower-level API methods (i.e. `new nodeio.Job`); see [this wiki page](https://github.com/chriso/node.io/wiki/Scraping).